# iOS Instruments Leaks stops recording as soon as app launches

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm facing a wired issue. I'm trying to run leaks using instruments to test my iOS app's allocations but as soon as I hit the record button the app launches and recording is stopped. App remains of the launch screen.

Tried reinstalling, removing cache, cleared derived data folder. But no gain. Has anybody else faced a similar issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Xcode version is 10.3
iOS Simulator iPhone 8 Plus 10.4

Comment: Did you solve it , I am facing the same issue

Comment: Not yet. Still looking for some help 

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I found. I was not able to attach any build with instruments. Not on the device or simulator.But if you run the app first and then launch leaks instruments from Xcode-> Developer Tools , then you should be able to attach your running build and check for leaks.